# Very few supported devices on Google Play

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I developed my app using cordova, uploaded it to Google Play but in the APK tab I can see that there are only 159 supported devices. The app is using network, GPS and storage. Any idea why it's not visible to more devices? This is the AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10001" android:versionName="1.0.1" package="com.visitacity.visitacityapp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="org.pgsqlite.SQLitePlugin" />
        <service android:name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background.ForegroundService" />
        <receiver android:name="jp.wizcorp.phonegap.plugin.localNotification.AlarmReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name="jp.wizcorp.phonegap.plugin.localNotification.AlarmRestoreOnBoot">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Try getting rid of the `supports-screens` property. If you are supporting literally all screen types then it is superfluous to add the property unless you plan to restrict a certain screen size. That may fix the problem... Edit your XML so it is more readable...put space between lines and have properties on top of one another so we don't have to scroll to the right forever to read all of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is located in the *supports-screens* or into *android:configChanges* so try to edit those tags

Comment: I removed the entire android:configChanges section and changed the supports-screens so it now has  android:xlargeScreens="false". Still, no luck, only 157 devices are supported.